# changing program function from fields to structure

Tags: c

is there any way I convert this program to using structures? I would like to do that but I have no idea how, but I know its possible. I am just begginer in this soI will be thankful for any kind of help. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int pole[100];
int x, i, j, q, min[100], max[100], min_cislo, max_cislo, min_pocet = 0, max_pocet = 0;

printf("Napis, kolko cisel chces ulozit do pola :");
scanf("%d",&x);
   
printf("Vloz %d cisla do pola :\n",x);
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    
        printf("cislo %d -: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&pole[i]);
    if(i==0){
        min_cislo = pole[i];
        max_cislo = pole[i];
        min[min_pocet++] = i;
        max[max_pocet++] = i;
        continue;
    }
    if(pole[i] <= min_cislo){
        if(pole[i] == min_cislo){
            min[min_pocet++] = i;
        }else{
            min_pocet = 0;
            min_cislo = pole[i];
            min[min_pocet++] = i;
        }
    }
    if(pole[i] >= max_cislo){
        if(pole[i] == max_cislo){
            max[max_pocet++] = i;
        }else{
            max_pocet = 0;
            max_cislo = pole[i];
            max[max_pocet++] = i;
        }
    }
}
printf("min cislo bolo: %d, na indexoch:", min_cislo);
    for(j = 0; j < min_pocet; j++){
        printf(" %d,", min[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
printf("max cislo bolo: %d, na indexoch:", max_cislo);
    for(q = 0; q < max_pocet; q++){
        printf(" %d,", max[q]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure. Just read up on using structures. e.g.: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: Hi, yeah I read it alredy but I am not able to connect it to my code.. :/

Comment: Don't look for a way to treat your problem as a nail just because you found a hammer. If you don't need struct, don't use struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to build a struct whose fields are the bunch of variables you have defined at the beginning. Well, as pointed by @"L. Scott Johnson", you don't have to. But if you want anyways you jus have to define a struct like this:

```
struct {
int x;
int i;
int j;
int min[100];
}example;
```

and just use the struct like this:

```
example.i=4;
example.min={1,4,5,3,4,8,99,123...  };
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it your like this because the quest was to save value and position of numbers into struct. see my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    int min_hodnota;
    int max_hodnota;
    int min_pozicia[100];
    int max_pozicia[100];
} bod;

int main(void)
{
int pole[100];
int x, i, j, q , min_pocet = 0, max_pocet = 0;

printf("Napis, kolko cisel chces ulozit do pola :");
scanf("%d",&x);
   
printf("Vloz %d cisla do pola :\n",x);
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    
        printf("cislo %d -: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&pole[i]);
    if(i==0){
        bod.min_hodnota = pole[i];
        bod.max_hodnota = pole[i];
        bod.min_pozicia[min_pocet++] = i;
        bod.max_pozicia[max_pocet++] = i;
        continue;
    }
    if(pole[i] <= bod.min_hodnota){
        if(pole[i] == bod.min_hodnota){
            bod.min_pozicia[min_pocet++] = i;
        }else{
            min_pocet = 0;
            bod.min_hodnota = pole[i];
            bod.min_pozicia[min_pocet++] = i;
        }
    }
    if(pole[i] >= bod.max_hodnota){
        if(pole[i] == bod.max_hodnota){
            bod.max_pozicia[max_pocet++] = i;
        }else{
            max_pocet = 0;
            bod.max_hodnota = pole[i];
            bod.max_pozicia[max_pocet++] = i;
        }
    }
}
    printf("min cislo bolo: %d, na indexoch:", bod.min_hodnota);
    for(j = 0; j < min_pocet; j++){
        printf(" %d,", bod.min_pozicia[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("max cislo bolo: %d, na indexoch:", bod.max_hodnota);
    for(q = 0; q < max_pocet; q++){
        printf(" %d,", bod.max_pozicia[q]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```